# how to get databases list at influxdb in v0.8

Tags: http, influxdb

how to get all databases use http api from influxdb in v0.8?

but I can use this query in v0.9:

```
curl -G http://localhost:8086/query --data-urlencode "u=todd"  \
--data-urlencode "p=influxdb4ever" --data-urlencode "q=SHOW DATABASES"
```

I can't get any info on influxdb.com

thx

Answer (score 17):

I can get the database list using this statement: `curl -G "http://somehost:8086/query?pretty=true" --data-urlencode "q=show databases"` My InfluxDB version is `1.2.2`

Comment: As of 1.2. the admin interface is disabled by default. The HTTP API with curl is a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

Using influxdb lib in python

install: $pip3 install influxdb

```
    from influxdb import InfluxDBClient

    client = InfluxDBClient(host='', port='', username='', password='')

    #return database in a list of dict
    dbs = client.get_list_database()

    #for better format
    list = []
    for db in dbs:
       list.append(db.get('name'))
```

Comment: `InfluxDBClient` object has no attribute `get_list_database`

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://localhost:8083 on the host machine. The Admin UI has a list of the databases configured.

Comment: As of 1.2. the admin interface is disabled by default.

Comment: As of 1.4 the admin interface is no longer available and is replaced by Chronograf